# sed: replace last field with value stored in variable if second field matches pattern

Tags: regex, variables, sed, replace, match

### Setup

I have a file with some lines which are incomplete, like the second one in the following example

```
cat file1.txt

7:|18.01-18.05|Un cambio a la partida 18.01 a 18.05 de cualquier otro capítulo.
7:|1806.10|Un cambio a la subpartida 1806.10 de cualquier otra partida, siempre que el
7:|1806.20|Un cambio a la subpartida 1806.20 de cualquier otra partida.
```

I stored the full sentence in a variable called `p7`

```
echo $p7

Un cambio a la subpartida 1806.10 de cualquier otra partida, siempre que el azúcar no originaria del Capítulo 17 no constituya más del 35 por ciento en peso del azúcar y el polvo de cacao no originario de la partida 18.05 no constituya más del 35 por ciento en peso del cacao en polvo.
```

### Desired output

I'm trying to replace the last field with `p7` if the second field matches `1806.10` as follows

```
cat file2.txt

7:|18.01-18.05|Un cambio a la partida 18.01 a 18.05 de cualquier otro capítulo.
7:|1806.10|Un cambio a la subpartida 1806.10 de cualquier otra partida, siempre que el azúcar no originaria del Capítulo 17 no constituya más del 35 por ciento en peso del azúcar y el polvo de cacao no originario de la partida 18.05 no constituya más del 35 por ciento en peso del cacao en polvo.
7:|1806.20|Un cambio a la subpartida 1806.20 de cualquier otra partida.
```

### Failed attempts

1. 

```
cat file1.txt | sed -E "s/(7:\|1806\.10\|\|)(.*)$/\1${p7}/g" > file2.txt
```

doesn't replace the third field for `p7`.

2.

```
cat file1.txt | sed -z "s/(7:\|1806\.10\|\|)(.*)$/\1${p7}/g" > file2.txt
```

gives the error `sed: -e expression #1, char 320: invalid reference \1 on` s' command's RHS`.

3.

```
cat file1.txt | sed -z "s/7:\|1806\.10\|\|.*/7:\|1806\.10\|\|${p7}/g" > file2.txt
```

replaces the last field but erases everything else in the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple `awk` program could help you in same. This is really an `awk` task, would be easier to handle in here compare to `sed` IMHO.

```
##Shell variable which has test value shown by OP.
p7="Un cambio a la subpartida 1806.10 de cualquier otra partida, siempre que el azúcar no originaria del Capítulo 17 no constituya más del 35 por ciento en peso del azúcar y el polvo de cacao no originario de la partida 18.05 no constituya más del 35 por ciento en peso del cacao en polvo."
```

`awk` code needed to be run would be:

```
awk -v p7="$p7" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} $2==1806.10{$NF=p7} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, passing shell variable `p7` into `awk` whose variable name is also `p7`. Then in main program setting `FS` and `OFS` as `|` and checking condition if 2nd field is `1806.10` then setting last field as p7 to it. `1` is an `awk`ish way to print current line.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed "/[^|]*|1806.10/{s/\(\([^|]*|\)\{2\}\).*/\1$p7/}" input_file
7:|18.01-18.05|Un cambio a la partida 18.01 a 18.05 de cualquier otro capítulo.
7:|1806.10|Un cambio a la subpartida 1806.10 de cualquier otra partida, siempre que el azúcar no originaria del Capítulo 17 no constituya más del 35 por ciento en peso del azúcar y el polvo de cacao no originario de la partida 18.05 no constituya más del 35 por ciento en peso del cacao en polvo.
7:|1806.20|Un cambio a la subpartida 1806.20 de cualquier otra partida.
```